# Tessnet2 error in C#

Tags: c#, tessnet2

I am using Tessnet2 ocr in C# by following codes:

```
 tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
            ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
            ocr.Init(Application.StartupPath + @"D:\\Program Files (x86)\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\AForgeTest2\\AForgeTest2\\tessdata\\", "eng", true);
            List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(numberTest, Rectangle.Empty);
            string code = result[0].Text;
            testBox1.Text = code;
```

but when I run the debug it shows the error message in the 5th line:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());//the line with error
        }
```

*FileLoadException was Unhandle:

Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.*

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Kind Regards
Gav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think changing the target framework of your project from 4.0 to 2.0 will help.

See: [Changing the Target .NET Framework Version or Profile for an Existing Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx%5E)

[image]

Comment: I ve change the .net to 2.0 but the whole project cant run under 2.0 .NET, is there any other methods? thank you

Comment: Sorry @achitaka-san I make a mistake, it no longer appears the warning now, but it stop the project when I debug it "Managed (v2.0.50727) has exited with code 0 (0x0). do you know how to solve it? thank you

Answer (score 8):

Try adding

```
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

to your App.config.

This enables you to reference that DLL without having to change your entire project's framework version.