# Tessnet2 Could not load file or assembly 'tessnet2_64

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tesseract, tessnet2

Please dont mark -ve it is basic. Hi, In my visual studio2012 I am using tessnet2 library for ocr but unable to compile the code. I have seen 
http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/
and have made all settings. I placed the tessdata folder in my .exe directory also. I have Microsoft visual c++ 2008 redistributable packages also (both x86 and x64) installed. My system is 64bit. I have also tried only using x64 package by deleting x86. I am using .net4.5 in my setting. I also tried other framework in my project settings. I have also tried x86orx64 or both in my project settings.
I have this code

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Amna\\Documents\\text.tif");
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
ocr.Init(@"c:\temp", "fra", false); // To use correct tessdata
List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

but I get this error: Could not load file or assembly 'tessnet2_64, Version=2.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1550524b5ba07e29' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
I have seen these links as well 
[Tessnet2 error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944778/tessnet2-error-in-c-sharp)
[IIS 7.5 Fixing An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728339/iis-7-5-fixing-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-pr/6754373#6754373)
and many more.

Comment: Did you check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053575/tessnet2-fails-to-load?rq=1

Comment: yes I checked this. it did not solved me. I am spending time more than 2weeks. and now when I search in google I get almost all links already seen.

Comment: I'm also having this problem now, have you solved it PrettyDoll>?

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely have to use the x64 version?  I was having a lot of issue until I changed to using x86 version of the Tessnet2 (tessnet2_32.dll).  I also changed my .NET framework target to 2.0. and making sure that the target platform is x86 architecture.  I also had to make sure that I have the correct language data in tessdata folder where the program executable is.  The data must also be a tesseract 2 data and not tesseract 3 data.